# how to split a mesh into two and duplicate common faces?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I have this funnel intersecting a cylinder. what is the easiest way to separate the funnel and the cylinder into two meshes keeping the lower half common?
[image]

Comment: I would just select the wanted pieces (the "rim" and bottom of cylinder for one piece, the whole cylinder for the other) press shift+D to duplicate,  right click so it snaps back to it's origin, and then separate (P) by selection. Do this for both pieces. That way you can get both shapes you want without destroying the original.